# Waking up a MacBook Pro M2 from sleep in clamshell mode without AC power

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, power, closed-clamshell

I got my MacBook M2 to work in closed-clamshell mode without AC power using the `pmset` commands. However, if I intentionally put the MacBook to sleep (using hot corners), I cannot seem to wake it up again. I have to necessarily open the lid to wake it up again. When connected to AC power, pressing a key on the keyboard or moving the mouse wakes it up. Note, that I tried `Amphetamine` and the `Closed-display mode` is greyed out. How do I wake it up from sleep in the clamshell mode? Any thoughts/solutions would be highly appreciated.

**EDIT 1:** Here are the commands I used:

```
sudo pmset -a sleep 0
sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 0
sudo pmset -a disablesleep 1
```

The MacBook Pro is a 2022 model - Apple M2 processor, 16GB RAM and 1TB HDD. The monitor is connected via HDMI, keyboard via bluetooth and Mouse via a wireless receiver.

Comment: What `pmset` commands did you use? Can you describe the hardware setup? Presumably you have a monitor (what connection?) and keyboard (USB, Bluetooth?)...?

Comment: @benwiggy, added more details to the Q.

Comment: TBH, fears of damaging the battery by leaving it plugged in are over-stated, now that the Mac will stop charging at 80% after a few days of continuous power. So there's no need to do all this, and still have problems.

Comment: While that maybe true, my pwn experiences tell me that leaving the charger plugged in, really does destroy the battery. Don't ask me how, it just does.